# Questions Related to the Twin-Prime Conjecture

Tags: number-theory, totient-function, conjectures, sieve-theory, twin-primes

For the sieve of Eratosthenes, let $E_k$ be the number of elements left after removing all primes up to $p_k$ and their multiples from the set $\left\{1,2,3,...p_k\#\right\}$ where $p_k\#=\prod\limits_{i=1}^k p_i$ is the [primorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial).

---

Then $E_k$ is given by

$$E_k=p_k\#\ \prod\limits_{i=1}^k \left(1-\frac{1}{p_i}\right)=\prod\limits_{i=1}^k \left(p_i-1\right)\tag{1}$$

which can be written in terms of the more general Euler totient function

$$\phi(n)=n \prod\limits_{p|n}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)\tag{2}$$

as

$$E_k=\phi\left(p_k\#\right).\tag{3}$$

---

After applying the sieve of Eratosthenes described above, the number of composites remaining in the interval $p_k<n\le p_k\#$ is given by

$$E_k-1+\left(\pi\left(p_k\#\right)-\pi\left(p_k\right)\right)\tag{4}$$

where $\pi(x)$ is the prime counting function. Formula (4) above corresponds to [OEIS entry A066264](https://oeis.org/A066264) which gives the number of composites $<\ p_k\#$ with all prime factors $>\ p_k$, and I believe [OEIS entry A285784](https://oeis.org/A285784) corresponds to the union of the non-prime values left after applying the prime sieve for increasing values of $k$ where values duplicated by different values of $k$ are deleted.

---

For the twin-prime sieve, let $N_k$ be the number of elements left after removing all multiples of primes up to $p_k$ and their associates (defined as pairs of numbers of the form $6 n\pm 1$) from the set $\left\{1,2,3,...p_k\#\right\}$.

---

Then I believe $N_k$ is given by

$$N_k=p_k\#\ \prod\limits_{i=2}^k \left(1-\frac{2}{p_i}\right)=2 \prod\limits_{i=2}^k \left(p_i-2\right)\tag{5}$$

which can be written in terms of the more general function

$$\phi_2(n)=n \prod\limits_{p>2\,\land\,p|n}\left(1-\frac{2}{p}\right)\tag{6}$$

as

$$N_k=\phi_2\left(p_k\#\right).\tag{7}$$

---

After applying the twin-prime sieve described above, I believe the number of non-twin primes remaining in the interval $p_k+2<n\le p_k\#$ for $k>2$ is given by

$$N_k-1+\left(\pi_2\left(p_k\#\right)-\pi_2\left(p_k+2\right)\right)\tag{8}$$

where $\pi_2(x)$ is the twin-prime counting function.

---

Formula (5) above is based on [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4524747) by user [buja](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/817477/buja) who claims to have verified it up to $p_{10}\#=29\#=6\,469\,693\,230$, but is asking for a proof.

---

The Euler totient function defined in formula (2) above is related to the [prime number theorem for arithmetic progressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Prime_number_theorem_for_arithmetic_progressions) and the [Riemann hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function#Riemann_hypothesis).

---

> **Question (1)**: Can the twin-prime conjecture be related to the growth of $N_k$ and/or $\phi_2(n)$ defined in formulas (5) and (6) above?

---

I believe $\phi_2(n)$ is related to $\phi(n)$ as follows

$$\phi_2(n)=\sum\limits_{d|n} (-1)^{d-1}\ \mu(rad(d))\ \phi\left(\frac{n}{d}\right)\tag{9}$$

where $\mu(n)$ is the [Möbius function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function) and $rad(n)$ is the [radical of an integer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_of_an_integer).

---

I've verified formulas (6) and (9) above are equivalent up to $n=10,000$. I tried expanding the product in formula (6) to a sum, but I can't seem to find a relationship between the terms of the expanded product of formula (6) and the terms of formula (9).

---

> **Question (2)**: Can formula (9) above be proven to be equivalent to formula (6) above?

---

The remainder of this question provides related information which perhaps provides additional insight.

---

Assuming formulas (5) and (9) above are correct, $N_k$ can be computed by evaluating formula (9) for $\phi_2(n)$ above at $n=p_k\#$ which is square-free and therefore $rad(d)=d$ for this case. So $N_k$ is related to $E_k$ as follows:

$$N_k=\sum\limits_{d\,|\,p_k\#} (-1)^{d-1}\ \mu(d)\ \phi\left(\frac{p_k\#}{d}\right)=E_k+\sum\limits_{d>1\,\land\,d\,|\,p_k\#} (-1)^{d-1}\ \mu(d)\ \phi\left(\frac{p_k\#}{d}\right)\tag{10}$$

---

Note that $\mu(rad(n))=(-1)^{\nu(n)}$ where $\nu(n)$ is the number of distinct primes dividing $n$ (see [OEIS entry A001221](https://oeis.org/A001221)), so formula (9) above can also be evaluated as follows.

$$\phi_2(n)=\sum\limits_{d|n} (-1)^{d-1}\ (-1)^{\nu(d)}\ \phi\left(\frac{n}{d}\right)\tag{11}$$

---

When evaluated at $n=p_k\#$, formula (11) above can be simplified to

$$N_k=\phi_2(p_k\#)=2 \sum\limits_{d\,\left|\,\frac{p_k\#}{2}\right.} (-1)^{\nu(d)}\ \phi\left(\frac{\frac{p_k\#}{2}}{d}\right)\tag{12}$$

which combines the contributions of odd and even related divisors $d$ and $2 d$ since

$$(-1)^{2 d-1}\ (-1)^{\nu(2 d)}\ \phi\left(\frac{n}{2 d}\right)=(-1)^{d-1}\ (-1)^{\nu(d)}\ \phi\left(\frac{n}{d}\right)\tag{13}$$

when $(n \bmod 4)=2$ which is the case for $n=p_k\#$.

---

I've verified formulas formulas (5) and (12) above are equivalent up to $p_{20}\#=71\#=557\,940\,830\,126\,698\,960\,967\,415\,390$.

---

When $k>1$, formula (12) above can be simplified further as follows

$$N_k=\phi_2(p_k\#)=2 \sum\limits_{d\,\left|\,\frac{p_k\#}{6}\right.} (-1)^{\nu(d)}\ \phi\left(\frac{\frac{p_k\#}{6}}{d}\right)\tag{14}$$

where formula (14) above is directly related to operation of the twin-prime sieve.

---

For example, consider the following table where $k=4$, $p_k=7$, $p_k\#=210$, $m=\frac{pk\#}{6}=35$, $d$ is a divisor of $m$, and $c(k,d)$ in the last column represents the number of times the divisor $d$ appears in a pair of associates when the smallest prime dividing the related associate is greater than $p_k$.

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
 d & 2 (-1)^{\nu (d)} \phi \left(\frac{m}{d}\right) & (-1)^{\nu (d)} c(k,d) \\
 1 & 48 & \text{-} \\
 5 & -12 & -12 \\
 7 & -8 & -8 \\
 35 & 2 & 2 \\
\end{array}$$

The first row in the Table above removes all primes up to $p_k$ and their multiples equivalent to the sieve of Eratosthenes. What remains is to remove the associates of primes $p_3=5$ up to $p_k$ and their multiples which have no prime divisor $\le p_k$ which is accomplished by the remaining rows in the table. The second row in the table removes the associates of $p_3=5$ and it's multiples which have no prime divisor $\le p_k$. The third row in the table removes the associates of $p_4=7$ and it's multiples which have no prime divisor $\le p_k$. The last row in the table compensates for the fact that two associates were removed twice, once by the divisor $p_3=5$, and a second time by the divisor $p_4=7$.

---

OEIS entry [A298826](https://oeis.org/A298826) seems to imply the twin-prime conjecture is related to the evaluation of the following Dirichlet series at $s=1$.

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} \left(\sum\limits_{d|n} (-1)^{\nu(d)}\right) n^{-s}=\left(\frac{2^{1-s}}{2^s-2}+1\right) \zeta(s)^2 \prod\limits_{k=1}^\infty \left(1-2 \left(p_k\right){}^{-s}\right)\tag{15}$$

---

There are many other Dirichlet series related to the product $f(s)=\prod\limits_{k=1}^\infty \left(1-2 \left(p_k\right){}^{-s}\right)$ appearing on the right side of formula (15) above some of which are defined in my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4528880), but I'm not sure if and how any of theses other Dirichlet series are also related to the twin-prime conjecture.

Comment: Quick things I note: (1) A major issue is that these formulas as written work only for $n=p_i\#$. (2) The twin prime sieve you notate doesn't seem to count the twin primes, as you're looking at elements left over, which would include non-twin primes so far as I can tell. I find working with the following twin prime sieve a bit easier, because it deals with directly removing residue classes: $$(6k-1,6k+1) \in \mathbb{P}^2 \iff (\forall p \ge 5, p \in \mathbb{P})(k \not \equiv \left[\frac p6 \right] \pmod p)$$ where $[]$ is the nearest-integer function.

Comment: (Those are just very quick notes though, I'll need to read through more thoroughly later.)

Comment: @EricSnyder The advantage of the sieve described in this question over your twin-prime-sieve is we have formulas for $N_k$ and $\phi_2(n)$. Granted $N_k$ isn't the exact number of twin primes in the interval $p_k+2<n<p_k\#$, but $E_k$ isn't the exact number of primes in the interval $p_k<n<p_k\#$ either. Yet the prime number theorem for arithmetic progressions and the Riemann hypothesis are still both related to $\phi(n)$, so it seems to me the twin-prime conjecture is perhaps related to $\phi_2(n)$, and note  $\phi(n)$ and $\phi_2(n)$ are not necessarily restricted to $n=p_k\#$.

Comment: Good points. Where does the $\phi_2(n)$ function come from? Is it from another reference or something you've created for this?  (I'll note I still haven't had time to thoroughly analyze this yet so grain of salt.)

Comment: @EricSnyder I defined it here and don't have a reference, but perhaps it's been investigated before.

Comment: @EricSnyder This answer at https://mathoverflow.net/q/435006 to my related question recently posted on Math Overflow provides some references where the function $\phi_2(n)$ has been studied before.